# Laravel dd function prevents blade including the master template

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I'm a newbie web & Laravel (version 4) tinkerer.  I'd like to understand why the dd function prevented my master template being included? For a few days I couldn't figure out why some pages had the master template included and some didn't.  In the end, through trial and error I realized that by removing the dd($variable) in the one's where the master was not included it fixed my issue.  It didn't matter if the dd function was commented or not, the master would still fail to load?  Look forward to any advice. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Marcin Nabiałek said, code in Blade comments gets executed anyways. So the `dd` stops the the execution of your script.
However if you want to have your `die` call in there, commented out but not executed, use PHP comments.

```
<?php /* dd('aaaaahhhhhhh i'm dying') */ ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel process code inside Blade comments so even if you comment something that for example throws exception it will still throws an exception. Comments make only that content won't be displayed but the code inside them will be executed.

And obviously as you included `dd` inside comments that displayes value and die it didn't display value but make the script end execution.